# Testing in Java Eclipse for Julian Date

Tags: java

I am having a problem with the testing of trying to fin Julian date of Eclipse. The (day month) from the testing are highligted red. Anybody able to help? Much appreciated.

```
public static boolean validDate (int day, int month, int year){
    if(month >=1 && month<=12 && day>=1 && day <=31) {
        if (day>30) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(month==2){
        if (leapYear(year)!= true&&day>28){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

//Array to store total days in month, not leap year
public static int julianDate(int day, int month, int year){
    int m[] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};    
    int total = 0; // to store total days

    // loop to add the number of days in each month, previous to the month chosen
    for(int i = 0; i < month - 1; i++){ 
        total = total + m[i]; //adding value in array at index position i to total variable
    }

    // checking if the month entered is after feb and also leap year
    if(month  > 2 && leapYear(year)){
        //total holds days in previous months and adds days in current month - plus 1 as it is condition of leapyear
        return total + day + 1; 
    }else{
        // no added 1 as the else is not leap year
        return total + day; 
    }

}
```

---

**TESTING**

```
else if (menuNumber == 2);
        System.out.println("Enter Julain Date DD/MM/YYYY"); //Here he print out Julain Date and asks for specific format dd/mm/yyyy

        int day, month, year = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        if (newDate.validDate(day, month, year) ) {
            System.out.println(newDate.validDate(day, month, year));
        }else{
            System.out.println("Not a Date");
        }
```

Comment: Have you considered using [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) ?

Comment: I havent as I am not sure how to use it and also it needs to be done this specific way

Answer (score 0):

Two things I see in your **TESTING** code:

1) You probably don't actually want the semicolon in

```
else if (menuNumber == 2);
```

but without seeing the rest of that if-else I can't be 100% sure.

2) In the line

```
int day, month, year = in.nextInt();
```

you are only instantiating `year`. You are not instantiating `day` or `month`. This can cause an error depending on your Eclipse settings. (and you probably wanted to instantiate them to something anyway). Eclipse will underline a piece of code in red if it believes that part is causing an error.